# XSLT Conditional Template Match

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements

I am trying to do a conditional match on an XML and to return the value from a sibling node. I would like to match on the records which have the attribute of Gender PreviousValue equal to an empty string. Then I would like to return the value of Number in ID for that slave.

My example:

```
<SlaveTeam>

    <Slave>
        <ID>
            <Number>202</Number>
        </ID>
        <Personal>
            <Gender>Female</Gender>
        </Personal>
    </Slave>

    <Slave>
        <ID>
            <Number>303</Number>
        </ID>
        <Personal>
                <Gender PreviousValue = "">Male</Gender>
        </Personal>
    </Slave>

</SlaveTeam>
```

The XSLT that I am trying to use is along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="/SlaveTeam/Slave/Personal/Gender/@PreviousValue = '' ">

    <xsl:value-of select="/SlaveTeam/Slave/ID/Number"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Because the second slave had a previous value of nothing for Gender, the output I would like to get would be:

```
303
```

I think I have a basic misunderstanding with how the matches should be used. Really appreciate any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
<xsl:template match="/SlaveTeam/Slave[Personal/Gender/@PreviousValue = '' ]">

    <xsl:value-of select="ID/Number"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Here is a complete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/SlaveTeam/Slave[not(Personal/Gender/@PreviousValue = '')]"/>

<xsl:template match="/SlaveTeam/Slave[Personal/Gender/@PreviousValue = '' ]">

    <xsl:value-of select="ID/Number"/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input

```
<SlaveTeam>

    <Slave>
        <ID>
            <Number>202</Number>
        </ID>
        <Personal>
            <Gender>Female</Gender>
        </Personal>
    </Slave>

    <Slave>
        <ID>
            <Number>303</Number>
        </ID>
        <Personal>
                <Gender PreviousValue = "">Male</Gender>
        </Personal>
    </Slave>

    <Slave>
        <ID>
            <Number>404</Number>
        </ID>
        <Personal>
            <Gender>Female</Gender>
        </Personal>
    </Slave>

    <Slave>
        <ID>
            <Number>505</Number>
        </ID>
        <Personal>
                <Gender PreviousValue = "">Male</Gender>
        </Personal>
    </Slave>

</SlaveTeam>
```

I get the output

303

505

So I think the match is as I understand your description.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to be working. It is not outputting any value. I put a flag in there to see if it was matching. It only outputs the flag once so it only matches once. Maybe I should have included that in my example - there will be multiple records and I will be trying to get the ID/Numbers of multiple employees.

Comment: I think the template matches elements in your input as far as posted. Of course the default templates would output text nodes anyway so you would get more output than wanted. I will edit to show how to prevent that. If you continue to have problems then edit your question with minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you want and the one you get.